# Create a bookmarklet for Safari iOS to print page?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, printing

Is it possible to create a JavaScript bookmarklet (or other link) to be used in Safari (iOS) that will automatically print the current web page to the default AirPrint enabled printer? Ideally without asking the user to confirm printer and quantity.

The use case is to set up an iPad at a theater that can let a customer fill out a form and then have the final page be printed to give to a staff member to assist them.